# Is there a reason why JUNIT is passing tests I'm clearly not supposed to be passing?

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm passing tests I'm clearly not supposed to be passing and I'm not quite sure why this is. Sometimes JUNIT seems to be frozen and just repeats one test output; I would like to know why that is the case
[image]

Comment: Is the IDE eclipse? If it is, most probably it's executing some previous cached version, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any assertion in the test.
Without any assertions, the test will pass.

The one you highlighted, if you executed it as it is, should not even compile.

Comment: The issue is that not only is the code compiling, the JUNIT test is passing! I added that as nonsense I knew shouldn't compile but it is compiling so I know something is wrong

Comment: @SSUT_Eco My first guess is that you might have answered "yes and don't ask again" to a "code doesn't compile, run anyway?" question earlier and now it automatically executes the last version that compiled. Try setting up a completely new workspace and recreate the test in it.